# How to transform Local camera frame to GPS or ENU coordinate

Tags: rviz, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
I am using ROS_indigo for  Tracking   marker  based camera poses.I  Have  camera  poses

```
          x                          y                                   z
```

0.121479289178           -0.106297347731            1.62793653837
0.786298557045           0.402245846399             1.54599247475
0.786059675294           -0.113879785059            1.58497680159
0.121330147186          -0.107066288802              1.62733927345
0.121800479286          -0.106119046842             1.62937524479
UI  want to transform these  point  in WGS-84  or ENU co-ordinate frame  from local.Could  anybody  let me know how I can do that  means In ROS  or any Papers  that I can follow for  standard positioning transformation.

Thanks  in advance.

Best
Taher

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240331/how-to-transform-local-camera-frame-to-gps-or-enu-coordinate/) by [btaher20](https://answers.ros.org/users/25814/btaher20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tutorial is a good starting point: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0